# dummy variable logistics regression to scores

Tags: r, dummy-variable, scoring

I have a logistics regression model where all the variables are dummy (0-1)

How can I convert the coefficients of the model to SCORES? (I need SCORES)

(classical methods all include binning - woebin techniques, but I do not do binning here because I already have dummy variables)

```
DF <- data.frame(
  Column1 = c(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1), 
  Column2 = c(1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0),
  Column3 = c(1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
  TARGET = c(1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0)
)

log_model = glm(TARGET~. , family = "binomial", data = DF)
```

Thanks!

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by scores (e.g. link to some of the "classical methods" you're talking about)?

Answer (score 0):

had a look [here](https://rdrr.io/cran/scorecardModelUtils/man/scalling.html) and tried to apply it to your data, maybe it can help:

```
DF <- data.frame(
  Column1 = c(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1), 
  Column2 = c(1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0),
  Column3 = c(1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
  TARGET = c(1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0)
)

log_model = glm(TARGET~. , family = "binomial", data = DF)

library(scorecardModelUtils)
DF$Y <- sample(0:1,size=nrow(DF),replace=TRUE)
x <- c("Column1","Column2","Column3")
iv_table_list <- iv_table(base = DF,target = "Y",num_var_name = x, cat_var_name = "TARGET")
num_cat <- num_to_cat(base = DF,num_woe_table = iv_table_list$num_woe_table)
scaling_tab <- scalling(base = num_cat,target = "TARGET",model = log_model)
```